# Sql query select first column value which has all value of second column select pt value who has all value of pm(1,2,3) in this table output should 1

Tags: mysql, sql

pt | pm

1  | 1

1  | 2

1  | 3

2  | 1

2  | 2

select pt value who has all value of pm(1,2,3) in this table output should be 1.

Comment: GROUP BY + HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT). Common logical division.

Answer (score 0):

select count(pm),pt from  group by pt having count(pm)=(select count(distinct pm) from <master_table>)

Try using group by, having clause and nested query.

Answer (score 0):

select pt, group_cocate(distinct pm order by pm seperator ',') as pml from table group by pt having pml='1,2,3';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).